# Javascript building table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my js file I am building a HTML table that may or may not have data base on the data being returned.

Is there a more streamlined way?

JS file

```
leftSideHtml += "<td><input class='form-control valid' type='text' id='txtName' name='txtName'";

if (data.SelectDrugIdDetail.ReimbursementDrugName !== "") {
    leftSideHtml += "value="
    leftSideHtml += dataName;
    leftSideHtml += ""
}
leftSideHtml += "</input></td></tr>";

$("#tblDrugInfoLeftSide tbody").html(leftSideHtml)
```

Comment: Are you have a specific problem? Define "better way".

Comment: That looks like an ok way of doing it, but you're missing several semi-colons from the end of your lines and you shouldn't be trying to close `input` elements with `</input>` - they're void elements.

Comment: If your solution works, and you're just looking for general tips and suggestions for doing it better, then this question would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
leftSideHtml += '<td><input class="form-control valid" type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" </input></td></tr>';

$("#tblDrugInfoLeftSide tbody").html(leftSideHtml);

if (data.SelectDrugIdDetail.ReimbursementDrugName !== "") {
    $('#txtName').val(dataName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ES6 template literals

```
leftSideHtml += `
    <tr><td>
        <input class='form-control valid' type='text' id='txtName' name='txtName'" 
            ${((data.SelectDrugIdDetail.ReimbursementDrugName !== "") ? 'value="'+dataName+'"' : "")}
        </input>
    </td></tr>`;

$("#tblDrugInfoLeftSide tbody").html(leftSideHtml);
```

Comment: I am getting an error expected ;

Comment: Srry, now it works, you can test it again